# Fade-Out Animation for Dialogs in Vaadin 14+

Tags: css, vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin14

I'm wondering if there is a way to set the fadeout animation of dialogs in vaadin-flow 14.

In Vaadin 8 you could use the css classes "v-window-animate-in" and "v-window-animate-out" to archive this.

Since the div of dialog overlay div is in the shadow-dom i can not access it easly through css.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it’s possible. And the default Lumo theme actually has a built-in close animation, but I suppose it’s so subtle you can miss it :)

Here you can find the built-in animations: https://github.com/vaadin/web-components/blob/master/packages/dialog/theme/lumo/vaadin-dialog-styles.js#L35-L67

Basically, you add an `animation` property to the host element when it has the `[closing]` attribute set on it (`:host([closing])`). The host element animation is used to track when the dialog can be removed from the DOM, so we are using a “dummy” animation on it with the same duration as the actual animations on the `[part="overlay"]` element. You can also animation the backdrop element (`[part="backdrop"]`).

Comment: First of all thank you! 
But i got one question left. How can i add the style to the shadow-dom style of the dialog? I know that you can define <dom-module> in the index.html. But i want to define them in an extra html file for this. Since vaadin removed @HtmlImport in Vaadin 20 i don't know how to archive this.

Comment: You should use a “custom theme”, where you can then add a vaadin-dialog-overlay.css file and place the CSS there. See the docs for more info (especially “Vaadin Component Styles” section on this page): https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/ds/customization/custom-theme